# Preserving undefined that JSON.stringify otherwise removes

Tags: javascript, json

How do I preserve `undefined` values when doing `JSON.stringify(hash)`?

Here's an example:

```
var hash = {
  "name" : "boda",
  "email" : undefined,
  "country" : "africa"
};

var string = JSON.stringify(hash);

// > '{"name":"boda","country":"africa"}'
```

Email disappeared from `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: JSON does not have an undefined value. What do you want?

Comment: You would have to change the value to the string `"undefined"` or perhaps `null` or an empty string `""`. How would you prefer it?

Comment: Check out http://json.org/ Note that in the standard value can be `string`, `number`, `object`, `array`, `true`, `false` or `null`. Note that `undefined` isn't an option.

Comment: PS: in a JS object literal, you do not need to quote keys whose values are legal identifiers. I.e. `{ name:"boda", email:undefined, country:"africa" }`

Comment: Africa is not a country :P

Answer (score 192):

The JSON spec does not allow `undefined` values, but does allow `null` values.

You can pass a replacer function to `JSON.stringify` to automatically convert `undefined` values to `null` values, like this:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(
  obj,
  function(k, v) { return v === undefined ? null : v; }
);
```

This works for undefined values inside arrays as well, as `JSON.stringify` already converts those to `null`.

Comment: ES6: `JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => v === undefined ? null : v)`

Comment: while this is a solution it does not solve the issue as it does not preserve the value as undefined, it changes it to null.

Comment: @Peter JSON only allows `null` values, there is no `undefined` value defined in the JSON standard.

Comment: @Flimm yes i know but this still does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Peter Is the issue that you think [the JSON spec](https://www.json.org/) should be changed to allow `undefined` values? Or do you not need valid JSON, but something else?

Comment: @Flimm i posted a solution that will keep undefined intact.

Comment: You can also do this with other non-displayable values such as functions `return typeof v === 'function' ? 'func' : v;`

Comment: If you want to really preserve `undefined` values, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72216472/1480391

Answer (score 12):

This should do the trick

```
// Since 'JSON.stringify' hides 'undefined', the code bellow is necessary in
// order to display the real param that have invoked the error.
JSON.stringify(hash, (k, v) => (v === undefined) ? '__undefined' : v)
    .replace(/"__undefined"/g, 'undefined')
```

Comment: I believe it's better to replace over regexp: JSON.stringify(hash, (k, v) => (v === undefined) ? '__undefined' : v) .replace(/\"__undefined\"/g, 'undefined') because your example will replace only first match

Comment: +1 on using the Regex. If you do so, note that there's no need to escape `"`: instead of `replace(/\"__undefined\"/g, 'undefined')` you can do `replace(/"__undefined"/g, 'undefined')`. Alternatively nowadays you can use [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

Comment: The problem with this code is that it will fail to work correctly for strings that happen to contain `"__undefined"`. Also, it produces invalid JSON that cannot be parsed by `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 12):

You can preserve the key by converting to `null` since a valid JSON does not allow `undefined`;

**Simple one liner:**

```
JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => v === undefined ? null : v)
```

Comment: What if I want to make it recursive?

Comment: "You can preserve it by changing it" ;)

Comment: If this is part of an API and your codding style is `if ( o.prop == undefined ) ...`, then you can say "preserve" the semantics, because only `null == undefined`.

Comment: I think we can replace 'k' with '_'  to indicate an unused parameter

Answer (score 7):

```
function stringifyWithUndefined(value: any, space: number): string {
  const str = JSON.stringify(
    value,
    (_k, v) => v === undefined ? '__UNDEFINED__' : v,
    space
  );
  return str.replaceAll('"__UNDEFINED__"', 'undefined');
}
```

Example 1:

```
const object = {
  name: 'boda',
  email: undefined,
  country: 'africa'
};
console.log(stringifyWithUndefined(object, 2));
```

Result (string):

```
{
  "name": "boda",
  "email": undefined,
  "country": "africa"
}
```

Example 2:

```
const array = [object, { object }, [[object]]];
console.log(stringifyWithUndefined(array, 2));
```

Result (string):

```
[
  {
    "name": "boda",
    "email": undefined,
    "country": "africa"
  },
  {
    "object": {
      "name": "boda",
      "email": undefined,
      "country": "africa"
    }
  },
  [
    [
      {
        "name": "boda",
        "email": undefined,
        "country": "africa"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

Note that `undefined` is not valid JSON and `JSON.parse()` will fail with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [...] is not valid JSON` if you give it the result of `stringifyWithUndefined()`

Comment: I might extend this to do the same for NaN. Using repl that overwrites console.log with JSON.stringify, and losing those values

Comment: I needed it to do `NaN` in addition to `undefined` as well. In case anyone else does in the future: `function customStringify(o) { return JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => v === undefined ? '__undefined__' : v !== v ? '__NaN__' : v).replace(/"__undefined__"/g, 'undefined').replace(/"__NaN__"/g, 'NaN'); }`

Comment: There are two problems with this code. First, it will fail to work correctly if the object happens to contain a string that contains `"__undefined__"`. Secondly, it will fail to produce valid JSON that can be parsed by `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `null` instead of `undefined`.

```
var hash = {
  "name" : "boda",
  "email" : null,
  "country" : "africa"
};

var string = JSON.stringify(hash);

> "{"name":"boda","email":null,"country":"africa"}"
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

Im reading between the lines here and guessing that you want to have the value undefined when you use JSON.parse?

If that is the case you could use the following:

```
var encodeUndefined = function(obj, undefinedPaths, path) {
  path = path || 'ROOT';
  for (var key in obj) {
    var keyPath = path + '.' + key;
    var value = obj[key];
    if (value === undefined) {
      undefinedPaths.push(keyPath);
    } else if (typeof value == "object" && value !== null) {
      encodeUndefined(obj[key], undefinedPaths, keyPath);
    }
  }
}

var stringifyAndPreserveUndefined = function(obj) {
  var undefinedPaths = [];
  //save all paths that have are undefined in a array.
  encodeUndefined((obj), undefinedPaths);
  return JSON.stringify({
    ROOT: obj,
    undefinedPaths: undefinedPaths
  }, function(k, v) { if (v === undefined) { return null; } return v; });
}

var parseAndRestoreUndefined = function(value) {
  var data = JSON.parse(value);
  var undefinedPaths = data.undefinedPaths;
  var obj = data.ROOT;
  //Restore all undefined values
  for (var pathIndex = 0; pathIndex < undefinedPaths.length; pathIndex++) {
    var pathParts = undefinedPaths[pathIndex].substring(5).split('.');
    var item = obj;
    for (var pathPartIndex = 0; pathPartIndex < pathParts.length - 1; pathPartIndex++) {
      item = item[pathParts[pathPartIndex]];
    }
    item[pathParts[pathParts.length - 1]] = undefined;
  }
  return obj;
}

var input = {
  test1: 'a',
  test2: 'b',
  test3: undefined,
  test4: {
    test1: 'a',
    test2: undefined
  }
};
var result = stringifyAndPreserveUndefined(input);
var result2 = parseAndRestoreUndefined(result);
```

`stringifyAndPreserveUndefined` will encode all undefined values in a array and when you call `parseAndRestoreUndefined` it will put them in the correct place again.

The one downside is the json will not look exactly like the object. In the example above it will turn into `{"ROOT":{"test1":"a","test2":"b","test4":{"test1":"a"}},"undefinedPaths":["ROOT.test3","ROOT.test4.test2"]}`

Comment: Long solution, but it works at least. (in my case, I just use the "convert to null" approach, since I don't need it preserved-in-json as `undefined`)

Comment: Why the downvote? is there a usecase where this does not work? if that is the case please provide the data so i can correct the function!

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not have an `undefined` value, but we could write a workaround:

## Preserving nested undefined values

I wrote 2 functions that internally uses `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` and preserves nested `undefined` values using a value placeholder:

Equivalent to `JSON.stringify`:

```js
/**
 * Serialize a POJO while preserving nested `undefined` values.
 */
function serializePOJO(value, undefinedPlaceholder = "[undefined]") {
  const replacer = (key, value) => (value === undefined ? undefinedPlaceholder : value);
  return JSON.stringify(value, replacer);
}
```

Equivalent to `JSON.parse`:

```js
/**
 * Deserialize a POJO while preserving nested `undefined` values.
 */
function deserializePOJO(value, undefinedPlaceholder = "[undefined]") {
  const pojo = JSON.parse(value);
  if (pojo === undefinedPlaceholder) {
    return undefined;
  }

  // Function that walks through nested values
  function deepIterate(value, callback, parent, key) {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      Object.entries(value).forEach(([entryKey, entryValue]) => deepIterate(entryValue, callback, value, entryKey));
    } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((itemValue, itemIndex) => deepIterate(itemValue, callback, value, itemIndex));
    } else if (parent !== undefined) {
      callback(value, parent, key);
    }
  }

  // Replaces `undefined` placeholders
  deepIterate(pojo, (value, parent, key) => {
    if (value === undefinedPlaceholder) {
      parent[key] = undefined;
    }
  });

  return pojo;
}
```

Usage:

```js
const source = {
    foo : undefined,
  bar : {
   baz : undefined
  }
};

const serialized = serializePOJO(source);
console.log("Serialized", serialized);
// '{"foo":"[undefined]","bar":{"baz":"[undefined]","qux":[1,"[undefined]",2]}}'

const deserialized = deserializePOJO(serialized);
console.log("Deserialized", deserialized);
```

Works with both object entries and array items.

The downside is that you have to choose an appropriate placeholder that will not be mistaken via a "real" source value. The placeholder is customizable via the optional `undefinedPlaceholder` argument.

This is specially useful to store [POJO](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) in browser [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ;)

See also:

- Gist: https://gist.github.com/yvele/f115f7dd0ed849f918f38b134ec3598a
- JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5jt2sf9/

Answer (score -2):

This will cause it to print as `undefined` but this is INVALID json, but is valid JavaScript.

```
var string = JSON.stringify(obj, function(k,v){return v===undefined?"::undefined::":v}, 2).replace(new RegExp("\"::undefined::\"", 'g'), "undefined");
```

Comment: The other problem with this code is that it will fail to work as expected if a string happens to contain `"::undefined::"`