# keep json nodes optional in a request payload

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am trying create json request body. where most of the fields are optional. I want to keep them if the value is defined for them or remove if they are undefined.

```
 
let payalod = data {
id: 1,
type: "sale"
name: undefined // optional 
}
```

I want to keep the name property optional. means if the value is undefied we can remove if before sending the request.
if guess it can be achived with a ? sing (optional chaining). but not able to get the syntax.

can anyone help me with optional chaining approach TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the object and `delete` the undefined properties:

```js
let payload = {
  "id": 1,
  "type": "sale",
  "name": undefined // optional 
};

for (var key of Object.keys(payload)) {
    if (!payload[key]) {
      delete payload[key];
    }
};

console.log(payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do ([Hide null values in output from JSON.stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115702/hide-null-values-in-output-from-json-stringify)):

```
data = {id: 1, type: "sale", name: undefined}

var payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
    if (value !== null) return value
}))
```