# How to display a row without showing its null columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I want to show all the rows in my table with all the columns except those columns that are null.

```
-- SELECT all users
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY user_id ASC;

-- SELECT a user
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_id = $1;
```

Currently my API's GET request returns something like this with the above queries:

```
{
   "user_id": 10,
   "name": "Bruce Wayne",
   "username": "Batman",
   "email": "bat@cave.com",
   "phone": null,
   "website": null
}
```

**Is there any way I can display it like this so that the null columns aren't shown?**

```
{
   "user_id": 10,
   "name": "Bruce Wayne",
   "username": "Batman",
   "email": "bat@cave.com"
}
```

Comment: You should handle this from JavaScript.  See [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-an-object) for how to remove null/empty keys from a JSON object.

Comment: You can use this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116529/6759368

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the help. Your comment led me to another page and I was able to solve my problem by following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57625661/16590740

Comment: You can make Postgres return such a JSON value if you want: `select jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(users)) from users where ...` I don't know Node.js, so I can't tell how it would handle that though.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using serialized (or deserialized) JSON and objects in your code. More serialized modules have special parameters that as `ignore nulls` and etc.

If you generate this JSON format data on the DB, in the inside SQL codes, then you can use Postgres `jsonb_strip_nulls(JSONB)` function. This function automatically removes all null values keys in the JSONB recursively and returns the JSONB type.