# JSON.stringify behaviour

Tags: javascript, json

I have below code -

```
const requestBody = { "username": { "$gt": undefined }, "password": { "$gt": undefined } }
const requestBodyString = JSON.stringify(requestBody);
console.log(requestBodyString);
```

When I print requestBodyString I get below output -

```
{"username":{},"password":{}}
```

Can anybody please help me understand why is stringify removing `{ "$gt": undefined }` ?

When I change requestBody with below :

```
const requestBody = { "username": { "$gt": "undefined" }, "password": { "$gt": "undefined" } }
```

I get correct output as -

```
{"username":{"$gt":"undefined"},"password":{"$gt":"undefined"}}
```

Comment: because  { "$gt": undefined } is not a valid json object. what do you think un defined should be in that case?

Comment: `undefined` is a value. `"undefined"` is a string. There's nothing specific about any string value - it gets JSONed as is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540706/preserving-undefined-that-json-stringify-otherwise-removes

this is might be answer