# DynamoDB / marshal function complains about an undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

When I try to persist my JavaScript object to DynamoDB using the `PutCommand`, I am seeing the following error message:

```plaintext
Error: Pass options.removeUndefinedValues=true to remove undefined values from map/array/set.
```

This happens when I use `DynamoDBDocumentClient`

When I use `DynamoDBClient` then I must first marshal the object using `marshall(..)` from `@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb`.  In this case the error is shown when I try to marshal the object.

When I print my object to the console, I don't see any undefined values. However, I don't see the complete object due to too many levels of nesting:

```js
{ id: 123, child: { anotherChild: { nested: [Object] } } }
```

So instead I use `JSON.stringify(..)` to display the entire object:

```js
{
    "id": 123,
    "child": {
        "anotherChild": {
            "nested": {
                "name": "Jane"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apparently don't have any undefined attributes, so why am I seeing the error message?

Answer (score 12):

The `marshal(..)` function will throw this error if it encounters an attribute that is undefined.

```js
marshall({
    name: "John",
    age: undefined,
})
```

My object *did* have an undefined value, but it turns out that `JSON.stringify(..)` will [remove attributes with an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540706/preserving-undefined-that-json-stringify-otherwise-removes).

I had to add a "replacer function" to `JSON.stringify(..)` to see (and fix) the undefined value.

```js
import {marshall} from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";

const myObject = {
    id: 123,
    child: {
        anotherChild: {
            nested: {
                name: "Jane",
                age: undefined,
            },
        },
    },
};

// Doesn't show the undefined value (too many levels of nesting)
console.log(myObject);

// Doesn't show the undefined value (silently removes undefined attributes)
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));

// DOES show the undefined value
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, (k, v) => v === undefined ? "!!! WARNING UNDEFINED" : v));

// The marshall function throws an error due to the presence of an undefined attribute
marshall(myObject);
```

Comment: I would use proper settings from my answer and not building something around it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786140/13055947

Comment: In my use-case, persisting an undefined value is considered an error, so I want DynamoDB to complain about it

Comment: Bad idea. Your solution doesn't make "dynamoDB complain about it" as you have said.  It will simply hide the real problem and store that ugly string.  You probably have a very simple validation bug somewhere.

Answer (score 11):

You should use the `translateConfig` object to specify the behaviour for `marshall` and `unmarshall` as described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html#configuration

You can use following [setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/interfaces/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.marshalloptions-1.html#removeundefinedvalues) to handle `undefined` values.